# Calculate a derivative

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I am given the following definition for a multilinear derivative:
Let $n,m,\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the total derivative of order $\alpha$ is given by the map
\begin{align}
D^\alpha f(y) &: (\mathbb{K}^n)^\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^m \\
D^\alpha f(y) &(h^1,\dots,h^\alpha)_l = \sum_{j_1,\dots,j_\alpha = 1}^{n}\partial_{j_1}\cdots \partial_{j_\alpha} f_l(y) h_{j_1}^1\cdots h_{j_\alpha}^\alpha \text{ for } l \in \{1,\dots,m\}.
\end{align}

Now I am given the function

\begin{align}
f(y_1,y_2) \mapsto (y_2,a(1-y_1^2)y_2 - y_1), 
\end{align}
where $a > 0$. Now I am supposed to calculate the following derivate: $f''(f''(f,f),f)$.

First one can see that $f''_1(f,f) =0$. Then I calculated $f''_2(f,f)$ the following way:
\begin{align}
\partial_1 ^2 f_2 &= - 2ay_2 \\
\partial_1 \partial_2 f_2 &= \partial_2 \partial_1 f_2 = -2ay_1 \\
\partial_2 ^2 f_2 = 0.
\end{align}
Thus I get
\begin{align}
f''(y)(h^1,h^2) &= -2ay_2(h^1_1 h^2_1) - 2ay_1(h^1_2 h^2_1 + h_1^1 h_2^2) \\
&= -2a y_2 (h^1_1 h^2_1) - 4ay_1(h_1^1 h_2^2).
\end{align}
In particular $f''_2 (h,h) = -2a y_2 h_1 h_1 - 4 a y_1 h_1 h_2$, whence
\begin{align}
f''(f,f) = -2ay_2 y_2^2 - 4ay_1y_2(a(1-y_1^2)y_2 - y_1).
\end{align}

But from here I struggle to calculate the desired derivative, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{K}$? The set of irrationals? (That's all I know it to be.)

Comment: @user477343 $\mathbb{K} is either the set of real or complex numbers. But in my example only real numbers are considered.

Comment: Ok. I use $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the set of real numbers; $\mathbb{C}$ for complex; and $\mathbb{R}\lor \mathbb{C}$ for "real or complex". Just note that in advanced topics like this, especially in regard to math, it is best to put forward the definitions of your notation.